# Extract value from xml file, simple example

Tags: c#, .net, xml

structure of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemsToProcess xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Item>somevalue1</Item>
  <Item>somevalue2</Item>
</ItemsToProcess>
```

I tried to extract values like this

```
 XElement elem = XElement.Load(filename);
 var items = from c in elem.Descendants("ItemsToProcess")                     
             select new ItemToProcess
             {
                 ItemValue = c.Element("Item").Value;
             };
             return items;
```

but obviously I'm missing something. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of results do you get? Shooting from the hip `UrlsToProcess` should be `ItemsToProcess`.

Comment: @SteveDanner, it was typo, changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a xml namespace that you need to specify.And if you need `Item` elements you can just use :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var items = elem.Descendants(ns + "Item")
           .Select(x => new ItemToProces { ItemValue = x.Value });
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx) to find more information about xml namespaces.